# Iptables hangs winecfg

Tags: iptables, firewall

I recently started using iptables and i found that when running the wine command winecfg it freezes until i disable the iptables service. I also saw that applications like tshark freeze when ran. How can i fix this? Am i missing something?

Here are my current rules:
[Screenshot][1]:https://i.postimg.cc/xT1BwHY8/Screenshot-20190707-005954.png

*UPDATE*
So it seems wine needs access to the loopback address of 127.0.0.1 but since i have the output chain policy set to accept, how is it still hanging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding the following rule to my iptables:

> -A INPUT -p all -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT